# Angularjs - How to make login page load instead of index page when giving weburl

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngcloak

I have created a web app where the user needs to login first.

When i type the url in the address bar and press enter, i first see the contents of my index page that is the navigation bar ,interpolation code where i bind data if the user is logged in and after that it is redirected to my login page since the user is not logged in.

Is there a way to load my login page first or just hide the contents of index page till the validation for whether the user is logged in is done.

for Example: i enter `localhost:3000` in the address bar

see

> Welcome {{authentication.userName}}

in my nav bar.

After the validation of authentication function it is redirected to login page.

I have tried using `ng-cloak` but it does not work.

Or should i make login page as index.

Comment: Which angular version are you using?

Comment: @Schlangguru angular 1.4.5

Answer (score 0):

how you used ng-cloak, for example if I want to hide and show the anchor tag as below I'll use ng-cloak as

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="demographic_lenguageAdd_btn ng-cloak ng-hide" ng-show="$index >=1" ng-cloak></a>
```

add following css for ng-cloak

```
    <style type="text/css">
  [ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], .ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
</style>
```

hope it'll solve your problem , just add css in the file or template and use ng-cloak with css in tag where you want to hide and show.